# iOS MediaPlayer Framework crash while live streaming a video

Tags: ios, live-streaming

i am developing the iOS application which live stream video with URl using iOS mediaplayer framework. That Application crashes randomly while live streaming. I had posted the crash report below. if anyone has solution pls help me...

```
 AVFoundation                   0x3701124f -[AVPlayer _attachItem:andPerformOperation:withObject:] + 1363

   AVFoundation                     0x3700d403 -[AVPlayer _insertItem:afterItem:] + 27

   AVFoundation                     0x37021fc5 -[AVQueuePlayer insertItem:afterItem:] + 129
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the one source of reproducibility for this issue, This crash occur whenever PUSH notification arrives to device.

This crash is due to improper handling of MediaPlayer framework when Application resigns Active and Become Active.

I solved this issue....